# How to share HttpClient between Multiplatform Ktor and Coil?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, koin, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, coil

I want to use Coil image library to load images from the api with the same cookie that was set before. Therefore I want to use the same HttpClient both for my Ktor networking calls and for Image Loading with Coil.

How can I share the same HttpClient between Ktor and Coil? I assume, I need to adjust dependencies somehow, but I can't wrap my head around it.

My KtorApiImpl in shared module

```
class KtorApiImpl(log: Kermit) : KtorApi {
val baseUrl = BuildKonfig.baseUrl

// If this is a constructor property, then it gets captured
// inside HttpClient config and freezes this whole class.
@Suppress("CanBePrimaryConstructorProperty")
private val log = log

override val client = HttpClientProvider().getHttpClient().config {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer()
    }
    install(Logging) {
        logger = object : Logger {
            override fun log(message: String) {
                log.v("Network") { message }
            }
        }

        level = LogLevel.INFO
    }
}

init {
    ensureNeverFrozen()
}

override fun HttpRequestBuilder.apiUrl(path: String) {
    url {
        takeFrom(baseUrl)
        encodedPath = path
    }
}

override fun HttpRequestBuilder.json() {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
}
```

}

actual HttpClientProvider in androidMain

```
var cookieJar: CookieJar = object : CookieJar {
    private val cookieStore: HashMap<String, List<Cookie>> = HashMap()

    override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookies: List<Cookie>) {
        cookieStore[url.host] = cookies
    }

    override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie> {
        val cookies = cookieStore[url.host]
        return cookies ?: ArrayList()
    }
}


actual class HttpClientProvider actual constructor() {
    actual fun getHttpClient(): HttpClient {
        return HttpClient(OkHttp) {
            engine {
                preconfigured = getOkHttpClient()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun getOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cookieJar(cookieJar)
        .build()
}
```

ImageLoaderFactory in androidApp - how to use an HttpClient instead of creating new?

```
class CoilImageLoaderFactory(private val context: Context) : ImageLoaderFactory {
    override fun newImageLoader(): ImageLoader {
        return ImageLoader.Builder(context)
            .availableMemoryPercentage(0.25) // Use 25% of the application's available memory.
            .crossfade(true) // Show a short crossfade when loading images from network or disk.
            .componentRegistry {
                add(ByteArrayFetcher())
            }
            .okHttpClient {
                // Create a disk cache with "unlimited" size. Don't do this in production.
                // To create the an optimized Coil disk cache, use CoilUtils.createDefaultCache(context).
                val cacheDirectory = File(context.filesDir, "image_cache").apply { mkdirs() }
                val cache = Cache(cacheDirectory, Long.MAX_VALUE)

                // Lazily create the OkHttpClient that is used for network operations.
                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .cache(cache)
                    .build()
            }
            .build()
    }

}
```

Koin dependencies in androidApp

```
@Suppress("unused")
class MainApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initKoin(
        module {
            single<Context> { this@MainApp }
            single<AppInfo> { AndroidAppInfo }
            single { CoilImageLoaderFactory(get<Context>())}
            single<SharedPreferences> {
                get<Context>().getSharedPreferences("MAIN_SETTINGS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            }
            single {
                { Log.i("Startup", "Hello from Android/Kotlin!") }
            }
        }
        )
    }
}
```

And then Main Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 
    val loaderFactory: CoilImageLoaderFactory by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalImageLoader provides loaderFactory.newImageLoader()) {
                MainTheme {
                    ProvideWindowInsets {
                        Surface {
                            MainScreen()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accessed the OkHttpClient  from ImageLoader with

```
class CoilImageLoaderFactory(private val context: Context) : ImageLoaderFactory, KoinComponent {
val ktorApiImpl: KtorApi by inject()

override fun newImageLoader(): ImageLoader {
    return ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .componentRegistry {
            add(ByteArrayFetcher())
        }
        .okHttpClient {
            val config = ktorApiImpl.client.engine.config as OkHttpConfig
            config.preconfigured as OkHttpClient
            
        }


        .build()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ImageLoader.Builder.callFactory{}` to provide your own `Call.Factory` used for network requests. The downside is you would have to map whatever type your `KtorApiImpl` returns to `okttp3.Response` which Coil understands.

Here’s a sample that describes how to implement the `Call.Factory` interface and provide it to Coil’s `ImageLoader`

```
ImageLoader.Builder(context)
            .callFactory {
                Call.Factory {
                    object: Call {
                        private var job: Job? = null
                        override fun clone(): Call {
                            TODO(“Not yet implemented”)
                        }

                        override fun request(): Request {
                            return it
                        }

                        override fun execute(): Response {
                            return runBlocking {
                                // Call KTOR client here
                            }
                        }

                        override fun enqueue(responseCallback: Callback) {
                            // Use a proper coroutines scope
                            job = GlobalScope.launch {
                                // Call KTOR client here
                            }
                        }

                        override fun cancel() {
                            job?.cancel()
                        }

                        override fun isExecuted(): Boolean {
                            return job?.isCompleted ?: false
                        }

                        override fun isCanceled(): Boolean {
                            return job?.isCancelled ?: false
                        }

                        override fun timeout(): Timeout {
                            // Your Timeout here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to follow the approach suggested by [H.Step](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7692155/h-step), and it used to work just fine. However, that was over a year ago and I assume things have just changed.

If you look at the type of `OkHttpConfig.preconfigured`, you realize that it *may* be `null`. For whatever reason, it *is* `null` when I try to access it.

A simple solution to ensure that the solution will keep working in this situation is to initialize it if it's `null`. In fact, this is what `OkHttpEngine.createOkHttpClient(...)` currently does under the hood. If you take a peek at the **source code**, you see the following line:

```kotlin
private fun createOkHttpClient(timeoutExtension: HttpTimeout.HttpTimeoutCapabilityConfiguration?): OkHttpClient {
    val builder = (config.preconfigured ?: okHttpClientPrototype).newBuilder()
    // ...
}
```

---

So, this is what I did:

```kotlin
class App : Application(), ImageLoaderFactory {
    override fun newImageLoader(): ImageLoader = ImageLoader
      .Builder(this)
      .callFactory {
          val config = myApi.client.engine.config as OkHttpConfig
          if (config.preconfigured == null) {
              config.preconfigured = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
          }
          config.preconfigured as OkHttpClient
      }
      .build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a dependency injection framework, you can attack this by creating a common OkHttp client and sharing that with Ktor and your other implementations

```
// Only OkHttp client to be shared
@ApplicationScope
@Provides
fun okHttpClient(
    interceptors: Set<Interceptor>,
): OkHttpClient {
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .apply { interceptors.forEach(this::addInterceptor) }
        .build()
}
```

Then inject it into your various implementations

```
@ApplicationScope
fun httpClient(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
): HttpClient {
    return HttpClient(OkHttp) {
        engine {
            preconfigured = okHttpClient
        }

        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
    }
}
```

```
@ApplicationScope
@Provides
fun apolloClient(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
): ApolloClient {
    return ApolloClient.Builder()
        .serverUrl("...")
        .httpEngine(DefaultHttpEngine(okHttpClient))
        .build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a composable function for creating ImageRequest and inject our httpclient into the ImageRequest:

```
@Composable
fun coilImageRequest(): ImageRequest.Builder {
    val httpClient: HttpClient = koinInject()
    return ImageRequest.Builder(LocalPlatformContext.current).fetcherFactory(
        KtorNetworkFetcherFactory(httpClient)
    )
}
```

And use it like this:

```
AsyncImage(
      modifier = Modifier,
      model = coilImageRequest()
                .data(imgUrl)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
      contentDescription = null,
      imageLoader = SingletonImageLoader.get(LocalPlatformContext.current))
```